# PHP not interpreted by browser on new webhost

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, hosting

Moving my website to a new webhost, I'm having an issue with apache / server conf files. PHP files aren't interpreted by the browser but only downloaded. I'm quite a beginner in that domain.

MySQL: 5.0.84

PHP Version 5.2.17

Apache 20051115

in .htaccess file, I wrote

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

to make sure every php file is read by php5.

Running a php info in the backend ( frontend doesnt interpret php ... ) shows well, if you need infos from it.

I really need some help, ty

Comment: A .htaccess file is useless if the server hasn't been told to look for them. Try adding the AddType to the main httpd.conf instead.

Comment: If this is shared hosting, I would recommend contacting your host and have them help you with this. There's probably not much you can do on your side of things. On a side note, PHP is always interepreted by the server, not the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php is interpreted server side.  so it's a server problem.

check your .htaccess to make sure it's picking up php.

might need to add a line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .phtml .htm .html
```